# Why does my monitor sometimes display a moira pattern (of sorts)

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport, kvm-switch

I recently bought a SIIG CE-KV0411-S1 (2-port DisplayPort KVM) to share an Asus VK278Q between my gaming PC and a MacBook. The Mac never gives me any trouble, but if the PC goes to sleep while it is selected on the KVM, when it wakes up, it looks like the attached picture. (Please ignore the moire pattern imposed *over* the pattern I'm referring to ,due to taking a picture of a screen.)

[image: Moire pattern, of sorts]

If I put the PC to sleep myself, then switch away from the KVM, it seems to be fine when I come back. If I try switching the monitor "off and on again" when this happens, the monitor won't come back. I've seen the pattern survive a normal reboot (but resolve when shutdown and restarted).

The video card in the PC is an "EVGA SuperClocked 02G-P4-2765-KR G-SYNC Support GeForce GTX 760," to quote the NewEgg order history. Is this effect the result of G-SYNC? Is there a setting I can configure to prevent this? I've tried running the PC at 50 Hz, but that didn't fix it! I'm out of things to try.

I'm specifically running DisplayPort from the Mac because I think VGA, DVI, and HDMI all look even fuzzier than DisplayPort on my monitor, which still isn't great, and which is the source of a lot of crazy talk on the internet, like, Apple purposely does that to sell more high-end monitors.

Barring a configuration fix, is this KVM just problematic? Is there another on the market that would be better?

I'm a little afraid to damage the LCD while fooling around with this. Is there danger of damage in having this happen?

Comment: This is cool. From the looks of it, every pair of pixel columns is flipped. G-Sync is only available with a G-Sync display, by the way.

Comment: I wondered if this was related to G-Sync. I looked for a flag in the display control panel, but never found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, a day after I posted this question, nVidia released a new version of their driver, and I never saw the problem again. The keyboard would occasionally drop out on me while playing games on the PC, so I've abandoned the KVM anyway, but I'm fairly certain that the video problem was fixed by the driver update.

Answer (score 0):

"I think VGA, DVI, and HDMI all look even fuzzier"  Sounds to me like your LCD monitor may be the problem, DVI and HDMI should be crystal clear (at the monitor's native resolution) since they are digital.

Try a different monitor (and perhaps different cables) to see if it behaves the same way. If it does act the same way, try a replacement KVM.

Comment: To be clear, all those options ARE crystal clear with the PC (or my Windows 8-based work laptop). It's only the MacBook that looks fuzzy on an external display. And, like I've said, I've debated that elsewhere, and that just seems to be a "thing."

Comment: Good to know.  Even then, I'd still advise trying another monitor, as it's the easiest thing to start with (as long as you have a spare I suppose).